# Transfer OCR data from one PDF to another?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I have software that lowers the image quality of a PDF when it performs OCR on it, but it has good-quality OCR that I actually want to use.

Is there any way I can "lift" the OCR'd text layer from it and place it back on the original?

Comment: Only a couple of potential causes of image degradation come to mind.  1. Is the original image stored at a higher resolution, and saving after OCR is at a default resolution?  If so, can you opt to save after OCR at the original resolution, or to add the OCR layer without modifying the original?  2. Are you sure that the original image is actually getting degraded, vs. the rendering of it is affected by the presence of the OCR layer?  3. What are you seeing after OCR--the OCR layer, and that's what's not as pretty as the original, or are you still seeing (cont'd)

Comment: the original and it looks degraded, or is the OCR result superimposed on the original and that's what appears degraded compared to the original?  4. Do you see the same degradation if you compare the original and OCR result using another PDF reader?  It's been decades since I used Acrobat, so I apologize if these are stupid questions, but those distinctions could point to different potential solutions, or suggest that moving the OCR layer to the original might make the original appear degraded, as well.  Any chance you could add before and after screenshots?

Comment: @fixer1234: Sigh... yes, it's really the PDF and not a rendering issue. Yes, it's the same in Chrome. I'm pretty sure it's just recompressing the JPEG. [Here's a screenshot comparing the two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5xJU.png).